# How can I show total expenses monthwise of current year in consolvetvs highcharts of bar type?

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart, laravel-5.7

I am using Laravel 5.7 and consoleTVs/charts version 5.* bar chart to show the total expenses month-wise of the current year. Here is my code what I have tried.

```
$expenses = Expense::selectRaw("SUM(amount) as total_amount, MONTH(date) as month")->whereYear('date', date('Y'))->groupBy('month')->get();
```

Query Output:

```
Collection {#273 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Expense {#275 ▼
      #attributes: array:2 [▼
        "total_amount" => "4014"
        "month" => 1
      ]
  ]
}


$chart = Charts::database($expenses, 'bar', 'highcharts')               
              ->title("Monthly Expenses")
              ->elementLabel("Total Expenses")
              ->dimensions(1000, 600)
              ->responsive(false)
              ->groupByMonth(date('Y'), true);
    return view('chart',compact('chart'));
```

But than I thought `$chart` might need only one value because in chart configurations it is already grouped by month of current year. So with map function I have extracted only `total_amount` from query.

```
$expenses_total = $expenses->map(function(Expense $expense){
        return $expense->total_amount;
    });
```

But yet I didn't got the expected result.

I actually want sum of monthly expenses of current year.

Comment: Hi Khushal Nayani, You used `highcharts` tag, but your problem is more related with `laravel` framework. If you have problems with Highcharts, please provide me with minimal live example and javascript code (http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/).

Comment: @ppotaczek I did't got consoleTVs/charts tag and I cannot create it as I have low reputation. The problem is also related to highcharts because when bar chart didn't worked I have tried line chart and it worked fine. 
Actual problem is I am unable to plot sum of the expenses in the chart. First I have tried `$expenses` variable in chart configuration it returned empty chart. So I thought `$chart` might need only one value because in chart configurations it is already grouped by month of current year. So with map function I have extracted only `total_amount` from query. But no expected result.

Comment: @ppotaczek And I was unable to create fiddle of laravel code.

Comment: Hi Khushal Nayani, Thank you for the description of the problem. I can not help you with laravel code, but if you describe in more detail what you want to achieve and provide me with your sample data, I will be able to create live example with javascript code which may be useful for you.

Comment: @ppotaczek All other charts with laravel is working fine except bar chart. But bar chart is working fine when I just counts number of expenses. I think the problem is I am unable to figure out what kind of data should be passed for bar chart. 
Yet now I have moved over with area and line chart in replacement of bar charts. Though I appreciate your help and support. Thanks !

Comment: I do not know what is the structure of your data, but please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/keth02q5/ and documentation: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.data, which show all possible data structures for Highcharts `bar` chart.

Comment: @ppotaczek Okay I will go through it. And Thanks !!